# Problems Comparator II of this CD4046 for LTspice

Tags: ltspice, comparator, texas-instruments, pll, vco

I downloaded a CD4046B model from user ale_t, which can be found here:

https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/new-spice-model-for-cd4046b-phase-locked-loop-ic.149093/

However, the Phase Comparator II is not functioning as intended. When I ground the input in VCO, I obtain a frequency of approximately 1.6KHz for the values of R1, R2, and C1. It was expected to obtain a similar value when VCOin is connected to LPF.

Here is a diagram of VCOin grounded at pin 9:
[image: pin 9 grounded]

These are the results when VCOin is connected to LPF:

[image: Pin 9 in LPF]

These are the values that I wanted, which were found in the circuit with an oscilloscope:

[[image: Autor Marco Túlio ][4]]

I suspect the issue is with the Phase Comparator II because when I disconnect R2, the frequency at the output is not 0, as it should be when I grounded VCOin in the same way. Therefore, I am looking for either another model for CD4046, a way to create only the Comparator II schematic in LTspice, or a solution to make the existing one work (assuming I haven't made any mistakes).

Comment: The 74HC series from both [Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd74hc4046a) and [Nexperia](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4046A.pdf) both show the logic diagrams for Phase Comparator II in their respective datasheets. You can use the LTspice built-in `[Digital]` elements like `buf`, `or`, `and`, `dflop` to create your own model by setting their A-device parameters: `Vhigh`, `Vlow`, `Tau`, and `Td`. Possibly tricky are the discrete transistors on PC2_OUT.  You can probably get away with something generic though, since that is what your existing model does.

Comment: I tried to replicate the [logic diagram for the CD74HC4046A comparator II](https://imgur.com/a/VzSYII3) from the [Texas Instruments datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4046a.pdf?ts=1679316898260), but I was not successful. The output frequency is much higher than expected.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem, but you can't use the default NMOS and PMOS models.  You need to define `.model` statements for them with at least `Vto` and `Kp` defined.  Otherwise it defaults to `Vto=0`.  Your `Td` and `Tau` look a little large too.  Regardless, I would try looking on the LTspice Google Groups files section.  There seems to be quite a few 4046 models there. I opened one up randomly and they use the `phidet` symbol under `[Digital]` to do Phase Comparator II.  There's an Educational example that ships with LTspice called `PLL2.asc` which shows this symbol being used.

Comment: The issue I have with Phidet is that the output signal doesn't remain in phase with the input signal, unlike the original PCII in the 4046. I require a certain degree of accuracy similar to the original CI so Phidet didn't work for me. Is there any method to make Phidet remain closer to the original phase signal? Additionally, I am unable to locate the LTspice Google Groups files section.

Comment: Sorry, I have zero experience with `phidet`.  You have to sign up for the LTspice Google Groups to get access to the files section.